# Is there a word for numbers between 10 and 99?

Tags: single-word-requests, numbers

I'd like to find such a word instead of saying "greater than 10 but less than 100".

Comment: 10s? i guess that implies 10,20,30,...

Comment: Do you mean greater or equal to 10, or strictly greater?

Comment: Others have mentioned _double digits_, but I just wanted to add that in some contexts, this can be shortened to simply [_double_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_(basketball)). For example, in basketball, when a player has a "triple double," that typically means he has scored at least 10 points, hauled in at least 10 rebounds, and made at least 10 assists.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Assuming you mean 10-99 inclusive, the phrase you want is "two-digit number".

Comment: +1 — and the nice thing is, this works for all number bases greater than or equal to 10. ¬_¬

Comment: @Robusto or less than.. if the context doesn't make the base clear, just write "two-digit [base] number" ("two-digit decimal number", "two-digit binary number", etc..)

Comment: @Thomas: The answer says "10-99"; that leaves out bases below 10.

Comment: @Robusto ... and by the same argument, it also leaves out bases above 10, as 10 is not a two-digit number in base 11.

Comment: Well, yes it is. 10 in base 11 is 11 in decimal. The number 10 in hexadecimal is the number above F, and the number above FF is 100.

Comment: @Robusto Ah yeah, my mistake. But I really meant that the "two-digit number" form is semantically valid for all bases, not just base 10 (and above).

Comment: Assuming you mean "10..100" (inclusive start range, non-inclusive end range), the phrase you want is "two-digit number", which will work for any base > 1.

Answer (score 18):

Numbers from 10 to 99 inclusive are often referred to as *double figures* in the UK.

For example, from [yesterday's (British) news](http://m.yahoo.com/w/legobpengine/news/more-snow-expected-thaw-065247393.html?orig_host_hdr=uk.news.yahoo.com&.intl=GB&.lang=en-GB):

> The death toll during the recent cold snap has hit
>   double figures - as forecasters predicted up to
>   another foot of snow is on the way.

Comment: ... and is *double figures* more a UK expression than US?  Where we would say *double digits* or even *two digits* instead?

Comment: @GEdgar: Yeah, being in the US I've mostly seen double-digit.  Double-figure is a new one to me.

Comment: In the OED, all the examples for *double figuress* were British, and *double digits* is marked as originally US.

Comment: @GEdgar: Good question. Here are the [2-grams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=double+figures%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cdouble+figures%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cdouble+digits%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cdouble+digits%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=): *double figures* has always been predominantly UK, but *double digits* has only in the past 40 years or so come to the fore in the US.

Comment: _Double figures_ would be more normal after a verb or preposition, _two-digit_ appositively, in the UK.

Comment: @Lynn Depends on context. I'm sure you've heard *six figure salary*  or that a jury awarded damages *reaching well into nine figures*. But yeah, agree that we'd never talk about a *two figure number* here in the US.

Comment: @Caleb - Yes, quite true.  I'm not sure why "six-figure salary" works but "double-figure temperature" doesn't :)

Comment: “Temperatures will dip down into the double-digits negative tonight.” “We should see triple digits for the next three days running.”

Comment: I have certainly heard "double digit" here in the US, but when I think about it too much, it sounds like "two fingered" :-)

Answer (score 5):

There isn't any context in the question, but if the context is something like

> The number of people at the meeting was between 10 and 100

then the phrase to use is *in [double figures](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/double%20figures)*:

> The number of people at the meeting was in double figures.

Comment: Hmm. I seem to have lost 2½ minutes on my answer. I wonder how that happened.

Comment: Sorry to have thereby invalidated your initial comment, but it just seemed daft to leave that inherent conflict between OP's original title and the text of the question.

Answer (score 5):

Commonly used would be "two digit" or "double digit".

- "Please enter a two digit number"

If you REALLY want to exclude 10 you could say

"Please enter a 2 digit number greater than 10"

Answer (score 4):

Not an exact answer, but I find it convenient in common parlance to talk about **dozens** of things. I hear this used more frequently than 10s when describing a rough quantity. For example:

> There were dozens of teenagers at the prom.

It tends to describe > 10 but with a fuzzier upper bound--an upper bound small enough that "hundreds" won't do.