# Is there a special word for amounts between 11 and 20?

Tags: single-word-requests, numbers

Translation is often tricky. I'm stuck with the Polish word *kilkanaście*, which literally means *few-teen*. It is used to describe an amount more than ten, but less than 20 (or including 20, it's hard to say, the next "about-the-amount" word means *twelve-and-a-few*.

Is there an English word describing that amount, or similar amount?

The reason for the existence of such a word, I think, is the fact that when counting on hands, it describes the amount which I can't handle using my hands alone.

Comment: After reading http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101698/is-there-a-word-for-numbers-between-10-and-99 I think that my question is also on-topic.

Comment: The word you're looking for is *teens*, which I am sure has appeared in answers to an almost-identical question in the last couple of days.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, 10–12 isn't normally included in "teens" (as much as my daughter may have claimed otherwise from her 10th until her 13th birthday).

Comment: @JonHanna, 10-12 used to be pre-teens but now have the label of "tweens". lol!

Comment: If you're talking about *numbers* (as opposed to *ages*), Anglophones would often refer to indeterminate values in that general area as ***a dozen or more***. If you used that term, it probably wouldn't be countered by *"Actually, the true number is N"* if N was in the range 11-19, but the further outside that range the true value was, the more likely it *would* be contested.

Comment: Related: [_How to use “tens of” and “hundreds of”?_](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/16356/5822)

Answer (score 5):

*Teens* is used to refer to numbers from 13 to 19, inclusive.

You can use this if you need a rough amount, and don't need to describe the range so accurately.

You usually use *teens* in this way by saying something is *in the teens*, for example:

> The temperature is expected to be in the teens tomorrow.

Alternatively, you could say something is *in the tens*, but this may be interpreted as something from 10 to 99, inclusive.

Comment: Maybe few-teen wouldn't so bad, only it's spoken almost like fifteen... but when written, isn't so bad...

Comment: If you use few-teens I would understand what you meant, but it sounds unusual and I'd be careful not to use it formally.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re just talking about people, it sounds like you’re talking about people in the second decade of their lives — although that would technically disinclude 20, since that is the start of the third decade.